# Where does the leading whitespace come from in this RDD and how to avoid it?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, whitespace, rdd

**string_integers.txt**

```
a 1 2 3
b 4 5 6
c 7 8 9
```

**sample.py**

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(^[a-z]+)\s")

txt = sc.textFile("string_integers.txt")
string_integers_separated = txt.map(lambda x: pattern.split(x))

print string_integers_separated.collect()
```

**outcome**

```
[[u'', u'a', u'1 2 3'], [u'', u'b', u'4 5 6'], [u'', u'c', u'7 8 9']]
```

**expected outcome**

```
[[u'a', u'1 2 3'], [u'b', u'4 5 6'], [u'c', u'7 8 9']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You split on pattern anchored in the beginning of the string so prefix will always be the empty string. You can for example use match:

```
pattern = re.compile("([a-z]+)\s+(.*$)")
pattern.match("a 1 2 3").groups()
# ('a', '1 2 3')
```

or lookbehind:

```
pattern = re.compile("(?<=a)\s")
pattern.split("a 1 2 3", maxsplit=1)
# ['a', '1 2 3']
```

or just split:

```
"a 1 2 3".split(maxsplit=1)
# ['a', '1 2 3']
```

Comment: `TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments`